# BFD: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '5', this reader only handles version 2, 3 and 4 information

Tags: c++, gcc, dwarf, bfd

I'm trying to update a complex project to use newer toolchain.

Previous toolchain: GCC 4.9.2; C++11; CMake 3.10.1; Binutils 2.23.52; GDB 8.0.1

Newer toolchain: GCC 13.1; C++20; CMake 3.26.3; Binutils 2.41; GDB 12.1

There are no issues with the old set of tools but when I'm using the new toolchain I'm getting plenty of DWARF errors like this:

> BFD: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '54929', this reader only handles version 2, 3 and 4 information.

dwarf version number was different on every error print.

After setting dwarf compilation flag to 4 (in project's cMakeLists.txt):
`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -lm -w -std=c++20 -gdwarf-4")`

I'm only getting a single error:

> BFD: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '5', this reader only handles version 2, 3 and 4 information.

It happens after calling `bfd_map_over_sections()` (declared in bfd.h) procedure.

Any ideas how to solve this? What I'm missing here?

I tried to use different GCC version, every GCC newer than 10.2 I'm seeing this issue.

Comment: dwarf5 support was added to GNU binutils back in version 2.29 if the changelog isn't lying. Perhaps something is still using the old binutils?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI,
Do you know what would be the best troubleshooting flow for verifying where old binutils used?

Comment: I would start with a full rebuild with the old binutils removed (or renamed temporarily).